# Function return a string and frintf() behavior in C language

Tags: c, return-value, function-call

I am learning how to function return a string in C. It has 2 ways: use static char array or use malloc. I have some experiments with source code be like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *repeat(char r)
{
    int x;
    // char *string = malloc(32 * sizeof *string);

    static char string[32];
    for(x=0;x<32;x++)
        string[x] = r;

    return string;
}

int main()
{
    char *a = repeat('a');
    printf("%s\n",a);
    printf("%s\n",repeat('a'));

    return(0);
}
```

I know this code will have undefined behavior because string doesn't have '\0' character in end. If I use static variable way, output is same in both 2 times printf() function called:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa☺
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa☺
```

But when I use malloc way, result is:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasers\man∩╒║2ü8
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

According to my understanding, the f() function will return the address allocated to the string, and because the string is not terminated by '/0', the printf() function will print some garbage characters like in`printf("%s\n",a)` statement. But in the `printf("%s\n",repeat('a'))` statement, no garbage characters are printed and I cannot determine what causes this behaviour.

Can someone help me explain this?

Edit: I'm just curious about how the pointer value returned by the f() function and the printf() function work leading to the difference in the two printed results. I tried run program in malloc() case many times, and in all time, result of  `printf("%s\n",repeat('a'))` statement always have not any garbage characters.

Comment: You need zero byte at the end of string. Add this before `return string;` line: `string[sizeof string - 1] = 0;`

Comment: It's called UB for a reason... You'd get different (still UB) results for the dynamic (possibly same as the static version) if you actually called `free()` between the two calls to `repeat()`... UB or not UB, that is the question...

Comment: In all examples, `printf()` eventually found a `'\0'` and stopped outputting bytes that were uninitialised. Notice that you twice invoked `malloc()` without any invocation of `free()`... In that case, there are two **unrelated** regions of dynamic memory (with different uninitialised values in their bytes) being passed to `printf()`. In the static version, the same block of memory was accessed both times...

Comment: A somewhat likely outcome of the UB is that `printf` will just continue its output until it runs into some random zero byte in memory. Or crashes if there is none.

Comment: The idea of using a `static char[]` is a terrible, terrible one. Because that string you got on the first return of the function will stay valid only until you call that function a second time. Sure, right now you are aware that you shouldn't do that. But will you remember in a couple of years, when you're expanding that code base for some reason? Or will you start scratching your head because your strings start "magically" changing contents for some reason...?

Comment: @DevSolar Thank you for the advice, I'm new and an C language course on Linkedin taught me use static variable way.

Comment: PS: Since your function is to set the characters of a buffer of characters, there's no need to multiply by `sizeof *string`. The size of a character is, by definition, `1`...

Comment: You might want to have a look at [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Most internet courses are... let's say, of questionable quality.

Answer (score 2):

Once your code invokes undefined behaviour, no specific outcome of any (number of) execution can be justified in any ways. From the language conformance point of view it's just undefined.

**Solution:** Do not write code which violates the language laws and invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for answer but I don't try to find a solution. I'm just curious about how the pointer value returned by the f() function and the printf() function work leading to the difference in the two printed results.

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains

```
    // char *string = malloc(32 * sizeof *string);

    static char string[32];
```

When you use the static variable, the return value of the function will always be the same address in memory where this static array variable is located. The memory contents after the last element of the array might belong to a different static or global variable. So if you don't modify whatever is located there, it is *likely* that you get the same memory contents on every invocation of your function.

Your way of using `malloc` will allocate new memory in every invocation of the function, and your code does not `free` the memory, so you **will** get memory at a different address every time. In this case it is *likely* that you get different memory contents.

It would be possible to change the `malloc` version to allocating the memory only once. In this case you would *probably* see the same result on every invocation of your function.

Example:

```
    static char *string = NULL;
    if(!string) string = malloc(32 * sizeof *string);
```

---

Whether or not you see garbage characters depends on where a `NUL` (`'\0'`) byte happens to be found after the end of the array.

If you allocate the memory using `malloc` and don't `free` any memory, then the memory contents after the allocated array size *may* contain all 0 because unused memory *might* be initialized to 0 after switching on your system. If you `free` memory, then you *may* see parts of the data that were stored in previosly allocated memory before or internal data used by the memory allocation functions. But you could also see garbage data left by programs that have been run before.

All this depends on the implementation, and you might see different behavior on repeated program invocation. That's why I wrote *"likely"*, *"probably"*, *"may"* and *"might"*. Even if it seems to work correct, this is undefined behavior.

Comment: Oh,  Thank you for an absolutely wonderful answer. But I tried run program in malloc() case many times, and in all time, result of  printf("%s\n",repeat('a')) statement always have not any garbage characters. Can you explain for this case?

Comment: @HaiPham "undefined behaviour" includes "apparently working fine".